# Moire effect when rotating rectangle using setTransform

Tags: javascript, matrix, graphics, html5-canvas

I've been playing around with using matrices to hold transforms for 2D elements in canvas. `setTransform` works pretty well for this, but I ran into an interesting issue where I get the Moire effect when I try to render a transformed cube at the coordinates `(0, 0)`. Setting the coordinates to `(0, 1)` or `(1, 0)` fixes this. Also the problem seems to only be with `fillRect`, rendering text instead of the cube works just fine.

Example Pen: https://codepen.io/danman113/pen/mdEYdKx

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution but I still don't fully understand why I was getting a Moire pattern. I would love if someone could explain that to me.

The solution was to reset the transform after setting it. I'm not sure why this works as I thought `setTransform` implicitly reset the transform after it was called.

```
c.setTransform(transform[0], transform[3], transform[1], transform[4], transform[6], transform[7])
c.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
c.resetTransform()
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/danman113/pen/dyXEGQw

EDIT:

As Kaiido points out in his comment, the Moire effect happens because `clearRect()` is also transformed. Adding the `resetTransform` fixes this.

Comment: `setTransform` does set the matrix to the absolute values passed (contrarily to `transform` and co. which do set it relatively to the current values). However, once set, the matrix stays like this (otherwise you couldn't use it). So when you were calling `clearRect()` at the beginning of your frame, your context was still rotated. Pathes are always antialiased, and clearRect using a rect path also is. So there the result of the antialiasing (semi-transparent pixels) was staying each frame -> moiré.

Comment: A great explanation! I didn't consider that setTransform affects `clearRect` as well as `rect`.